# Combining Document Classes

Tags: document-classes, include

I have a complicated document containing files with a letter as the first document followed by several article type documents.  I have done this by setting up a master tex file with all the frontpeice information, defining common style elements and whatnot, then adding the documents with \include statements.  Is there a way to use the letter document class for the first file then switch to the article class for the rest of the files?

Answer (score 6):

[This FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multidoc) discusses some solutions to this type of problem. The only one that I think is likely to work for you in this case, is the `pdfpages` based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but the `combine` document class *might* do what you want. Unfortunately, it also tends to conflict with a lot of things, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is going to be an easy way to do what you want. You could move all of the "common style elements" into a a .sty file that you can then use via `\usepackage` from your other documents.