How to enable my thesis to have different formats for each chapter?
I am writing my thesis of which some chapters are based on my published papers. At my university, there are two types of theses: those by monograph and those by publication. My thesis falls under the latter category, which means I need to include my published papers as chapters. I have four papers that make up chapters 3, 4, 5, and 6 of my thesis. After my defence, the panel recommended that I retain the journal format for each paper within the thesis. As a result, each chapter will have a different format. For instance, chapter 3 is in Springer format and chapter 3 is in IEEEtran format. Does anyone know how to realise this? Thanks a lot.


I am not too sure what you asking is correct. I presume your thesis is a book type, whereas the journals are article-like, they do not have chapter commands. Please provide a MWE with your thesis template and one chapter. I guess what you are after is to use the title of the papers! However, normally your own publishd papers are best put at the back of the thesis as appendices (include the pdfs) or even better, just reference them, so that you are not accused of padding your thesis.

Hi Yannisl, thank you very much for your reply. At my university, there are two types of theses: those by monograph and those by publication. My thesis falls under the latter category, which means I need to include my published papers as chapters. I have four papers that make up chapters 3, 4, 5, and 6 of my thesis. After my defense, the panel recommended that I retain the journal format for each paper within the thesis. As a result, each chapter will have a different format, and I'm unsure how to manage this.

If I understand your problem correctly, I think using the documentclass memoir could solve it.
The class gives you the ability to create many page styles that you can use for the various texts to be inserted.
There would be another possibility, simpler but perhaps more laborious. With a scanner you acquire your writings and insert them into your thesis as images.

The easiest thing would be to A) use pdfpages https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages and B) have different chapters based on whatever documentclass. // This way you can assemble all your format vaying own compiled papers into a main document and/or include whatever cited paper in its original format.

Weclome // I suggest to EDIT your question and clarify it a bit more. Please use the comments made for this. Please add screenshots if possible. Thank you

@MS-SPO Thank you for your suggestions. You're absolutely right, using the pdfpages package is indeed the easiest solution. However, this approach doesn't allow for the automatic generation of the 'List of Figures' and 'List of Tables'. Therefore, I believe it would be more elegant to assign different document classes to different chapters. However, I'm unsure how to implement this. For example, I'd like to use the IEEEtran document class specifically for Chapter 5 (\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}).

Thank you. // From your (incompete) question I read that you are not the first one at your university facing this request: A) How does you university support this, e.g. via dedicated templates? B) How did other solve this at your university?

Wrt TOC, it's a question of what's easier to obtain: A) using the \addto.. feature from pdfpages  "manually" (as your cited doicumets probably won't change anymore), B) fiddling with various documentclasses into one big one? // Searching here [document-classes] several leads e.g. to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3225/245790, which refers to https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multidoc . // You may also try autmating use of .aux/.toc from the various compiles, i.e. extracting and adjusting information from the compiles.

Please, don't use screenshots to show code ... copy it and mark it as code, instead, using the { } -es. Thank you

Here is a way to do it. Result:


Prerequisite for this demo
Download these two pdf-docs used and store them locally:

IEEE https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.10273
PhysRevD https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84146551.pdf

Save the full code as main.tex.
Remarks
Unless your cited publications stretch 100s of pages, the following should be easy to do, with little room left for errors. I.e. it's still a good balance between effort and result.
To simplify handling and changing in one place only I defined these commands as shortcut to the pdfs:
% ~~~ document names ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\doca[0]{1907.10273v1.pdf}
\newcommand\docb[0]{84146551.pdf}

The key activitiy is to use \includepdf AND to specify the desired table entries, like shown below. You can add more entries for the figures and tables, see the manual.
Because these documents start with a page linking to the respective digital libraries, I skip the first page. The page numbers are the 1st, snd etc. in the pdf. last is the last page.
In addtotoc you can also specify a label references can be made to. See final code for a few references I made (and are hyperlinked, too, im main.pdf). This option assumes a list grouped in 5er entries, separated by comma; so just continue adding more (with a new ,).
  \includepdf[pages={2-last},
    addtotoc={
        2,section,1,Introduction,a:intro,
        3,section,1,Proposed Algorithm,a:algo
    }]{\doca}

I used \vref very simple as demonstration. In a real document I'd put it inside e.g. \newcommand\reffig[1]{Figure \vref{fig:#1}} or so, assuming fig:a, fig:b etc. used as labels.

\documentclass[12pt,twosided,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}   % obvious
\usepackage{lipsum}     % blindtext
\usepackage{hyperref}   % enable links
\usepackage{varioref}   % nice references

% ~~~ document names ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\doca[0]{1907.10273v1.pdf}
\newcommand\docb[0]{84146551.pdf}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

 \chapter{So it begins}
 \section{abc}

 You can refer to labels set in the included pdf, like \vref{a:algo} for the IEEE document and \vref{b:motiv} for the PhsyRevD.
 
 \lipsum[10-11]

 \chapter{First IEEE document}
 The first dacument is taken from \url{https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.10273}. Its first page links to the IEEE Digital Explorer and is skipped here.

 % for many entries see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15995/245790
 
  \includepdf[pages={2-last},
    addtotoc={
        2,section,1,Introduction,a:intro,
        3,section,1,Proposed Algorithm,a:algo
    }]{\doca}
    
 \chapter{Some article from PHYSICAL REVIEW D}
    For simplicity only the first two pages are included here. Again, the first page is skipped for the download version at \url{https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84146551.pdf}.
    
  \includepdf[pages={2-3},
    addtotoc={
        2,section,1,Introduction,b:intro,
        3,section,1,Motivation for this study,b:motiv
    }]{\docb}


\end{document}


Thank you so much for your detailed guidance, @MS-SPO. I followed your method, and it worked quite well—almost exactly as I wanted. I also used \trim and \clip to remove the original page numbers displayed on the journal paper pages. My problem is solved!

Great :) // May be your clipping approach is worth to be documented as an answer to your own question for future readers? I.e. consider posting a new question with focus on removal AND answer it yourself.
